# Why is DC not giving enough time to Big Villain characters?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe

Both in *Batman V Superman* and in *Wonder Woman*, DC introduced 2 major negative characters - Doomsday and Ares.

Doomsday, one of the few characters who

> has managed to kill Superman

and feeds on energy and has multiple evolutions, but was not there for even 30 minutes.

Being a *God of War*, Ares should be really good at fighting and in battle strategies,

> but again was given very less screen time and was defeated very easily.

So my question is, why is DC not focusing on villains? Why are they just focusing on Superheros and their abilities?

Comment: First off, Suicide Squad is a movie about villains. Second, Lex Luthor was kind of big deal in BvS and he is a villain. Third, I simply assume DC decided to explore psychology and character interaction. Doomsday isn't much of a talker, so that's maybe why he got such a short screentime. I haven't seen WW yet, so I can't analyze that.

Comment: A similar criticism can be made of many of the Marvel movies.

Comment: @doomista Sorry for spoiler then. Also for Doomsday, yes he is not a talker,  but none the less he is a very big character. And doing 2 evolution and killing him in a span of few mins is bad. Yes Lex is a major villain himself, but he is more architect who plays intricate games. But as a head-on fighter, Doomsday fits right and that gives lot of scope to explore skills of heros like Batman and Wonder Woman.

Comment: @Ixrec true but lets not compare both as that can attract unwanted opinionated discussions. Also, considering negative characters like Loki or Winter Soldier or Ultron or even Malekith, they were given a lot of detailing. DC just brings a big character for climax fight and kills it. This in my understanding is bad

Comment: @Rajesh: "Being a God of War, Ares should be really good at fighting and in battle strategies" That is _exactly_ why you don't want him front and center. He's too much of a deus ex machina.

Comment: @Rajesh Ares is a whiny little asshole that generally runs away as soon as he gets hurt. Athena is the type of war god you are thinking of.

Comment: @Flater if you have seen the movie, then you would agree that ares is a big character, but was defeated very easily and quickly. Same thing happened with Doomsday. I know the question is based on my opinion and is correctly closed, but will you not agree that DC is introducing big character but are not justifying them.

Comment: @Rajesh: There is no fun in watching an omnipotent character be good at everything. Ares dying quickly prevents that from happening. He is a big character (he is a deity after all), but that's not the same as being the **main focus** of the movie. The same applies to Gandalf, Obi Wan, Yoda, a benevolent Q in every TNG episode, ... these characters wield too much power for any plot revolving around them to be exciting or filled with tension. Pretty much any plot is supposed to revolve around weak, ignorant and fallible protagonists. Because they have a journey to go on.

Comment: How much time would be enough Rajesh? If you can give specifics, DC can run all future decisions past you to ensure they don’t make mistakes like these again.